How can I use a custom connection-listener in my datasource using quarkus with panache?
I have a legacy JEE application that is deployed in JBOSS EAP that I am migrating to quarkus, currently the datasource of this application uses a custom connection-listener that is configured in the property

....

...
<connection-listener class-name="my.package.CustomConnecionListener"...
This class adds data to some properties to trace my java application using for example:
Oracle.END_TO_END_STATE_INDEX_MAX
I do not know where to start
